# Open declarations with eclipse, PHP and RSE

Tags: php, eclipse, remote-access

I've set up a remote project with Eclipse Helios and the [RSE plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/tm/).

Auto-completion works but I can not use <kbd>F3</kbd> (follow declarations). It doesn't if the declaration is in the same file and of course doesn't work if the declaration in another file.

Is there any way to get the declaration tools working with RSE?

Answer (score 7):

ok found the solution: I had to add "php support" (right click project -> Configure -> add php support) and run "refresh project" "F5".

Answer (score 0):

in Eclipse 3.4 (Ganymede) I fixed this manually editing the .projects file

```
<natures>
    <nature>org.eclipse.php.core.PHPNature</nature>
</natures>
```